# Custom Smarty functions

Tags: php, smarty

In Smarty i want to be able to write {widget 15} or {widget id=15} , so the output will be the return value of PHP function

```
function widget($id){
    echo 'hi '.$id;
}
```

is it possible ?

Comment: yes, look [here](http://www.velvetblues.com/web-development-blog/smarty-templates-create-custom-functions/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Smarty allows you to create such custom functions easily: [see the official reference](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/plugins.functions.tpl).